# How can I count the number and calculate it? (i using isNaN())

Tags: javascript

My code is below. I'm using `isNaN()` but the problem is it's still valid

```js
function numberSearch(str) {
  let sum = 0
  let strCount = 0
  
  if (str === "") {
    return 0
  };
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
      strCount = strCount + 1 // if it's true, +1
    }
    
    sum = sum + Number(str[i]) // if it's a number 
  }
  
  return Math.round(sum / strCount);
}

//debugger;

let output = numberSearch('Hello6 ');
console.log(output); // --> 1

output = numberSearch('Hello6 9World 2,');
console.log(output); // --> 1
```

How can I count the number and calculate it?

When I using debugger sum is `NaN` .. I cant understand well.

Comment: You need a `continue;` inside the if branch of `isNaN(Number(str[i]))` otherwise sum will still happen with the NaN number

Comment: you mean for loop sentence doesnt work anymore ??

Comment: No, [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) just goes to the next element in your for statement, without executing any of the statements below it

Comment: @Icepickle thank you . your tip is valid!! but i need to choose answer xd

Comment: I added one with an alternative code and one that shows how to use the `continue` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `sum = sum + Number(str[i])` is being executed even if `isNaN(Number(str[i])) === true` because it is outside of the `if` block. You need to wrap it inside of the `else` block so that it only executes if the previous condition is false.

```js
function numberSearch(str) {
  let sum = 0
  let strCount = 0

  if (str === "") {
    return 0
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
      strCount = strCount + 1 // if it's true, +1
    } else {
      sum = sum + Number(str[i]) // if it's a number 
    }
  }

  return Math.round(sum / strCount);
}

//debugger;

let output = numberSearch('Hello6 ');
console.log(output); // --> 1

output = numberSearch('Hello6 9World 2,');
console.log(output); // --> 1
```

The other way of doing this is with a `continue` statement. Think of `continue` the same way you think about an early `return` in a function, except for a loop.

For example, you've written:

```js
function numberSearch(str) {
  // . . .

  if (str === "")
    return 0

  // . . .
}
```

This is called an "early return" or "early exit." The same technique can be used in a loop:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 3 === 0) // matches every multiple of 3 (3, 6, 9, etc.)
    continue;

  console.log(i)
}
```

Here is your code again, this time using `continue`.

```js
function numberSearch(str) {
  let sum = 0
  let strCount = 0

  if (str === "") {
    return 0
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
      strCount = strCount + 1 // if it's true, +1
      continue
    }

    sum = sum + Number(str[i]) // if it's a number 
  }

  return Math.round(sum / strCount);
}

//debugger;

let output = numberSearch('Hello6 ');
console.log(output); // --> 1

output = numberSearch('Hello6 9World 2,');
console.log(output); // --> 1
```

I recommend you go with the `if-else` version because for a loop as simple as this, the use of `continue` adds a little unnecessary metal-overhead.
That being said, if the logic within the loop grows (the part in the `else` statement), you may find it is easy to read if you *do* use the `continue` method. In the end, what really matters is what you personally feel is easier to read.

Comment: that's a good way as well, but it does add more blocks and can become very confusing once more conditions come :)

Comment: @Icepickle I'd argue that if more conditions were required, that they should be refactored into separate functions.

Comment: That's a fair one :)

Comment: Just one more test Justin :) `numberSearch('111111')`

Comment: @Icepickle oof. Good catch.

Comment: @Loolii glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably do it slightly different than in the original code, and find out how many numbers there are, and work from there

```js
function numberSearch(str) {
  if (!str) {
    // early exit for null or ''
    return 0;
  }
  // get all the chars, filter the non-numbers
  const numbers = str.split('').filter( v => !isNaN(Number(v)));
  // map all the numbers to numbers and sum them up
  const sum = numbers.map( Number ).reduce( (agg, item) => agg + item, 0 );
  // divide the sum by the length of the string - the amount of numbers found
  // but always by at least 1 (so not to get a divide by 0 error when only all numbers are given)
  return Math.round( sum / Math.max(1, str.length - numbers.length) );
}

let output = numberSearch('Hello6 ');
console.log(output); // --> 1

output = numberSearch('Hello6 9World 2,');
console.log(output); // --> 2

output = numberSearch('111111111');
console.log(output); // --> 9

output = numberSearch('');
console.log(output);
```

For the original code however, you should just add a `continue` in your if branch and your code will work (as long as not all characters are numbers, cause then you would divide by 0 and you didn't specify how to handle such a case)

```
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
    strCount = strCount + 1; // if it's true, +1
    continue;
  }
  
  sum = sum + Number(str[i]); // if it's a number 
}
```

Just remember to verify to not divde by 0 if all are numbers :)

Comment: Ohhh okay i will :) thank you for your tip. your tip was critically correct !!

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is that you add a number anyway. In the line `sum = sum + Number(str[i])`  is read for each and every character. So even the last char will be `NaN` and it would be added to the sum, making it `NaN`.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do here, it seems like you are trying to get the sum and divide it by the number of non number characters.

You need to skip those in the sum. There are plenty of ways to do it, and some other problems with the code, but to keep the changes to your code to a minimum I say, just do this:

```
function numberSearch(str) {
  let sum = 0;
  let strCount = 0;
  
  if (str === "") {
    return 0;
  };
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (isNaN(Number(str[i]))) {
      strCount = strCount + 1; // if it's true, +1
    } else {
      sum = sum + Number(str[i]); // if it's a number 
    }
  }
  return Math.round(sum / strCount);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer :)  "You need to skip those in the sum" 
 yes i will :).  i understand more thanks for your favor :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of the following case

```
 for(let i = 0 ; i<str.length ; i++){

    //str[0] is 'H', so fall into the first if-case
    if(isNaN(Number(str[i]))){
      strCount = strCount + 1   // if it's true, +1
    }

    //the code keep running but 'H' shouldn't fall into the following case 
    sum = sum + Number(str[i]) // if it's a number     
}
        
return Math.round(sum/strCount);
```

I suggest you add one more `if-else` for each case which clearly state out each of the case. This makes it easier to recall memory when you come across the code days or months later.

```
 for(let i = 0 ; i<str.length ; i++){
    if(isNaN(Number(str[i]))){
      strCount = strCount + 1 
    }else if(typeof str[i] === 'number'){
       sum = sum + Number(str[i])
    } 
  }

  return Math.round(sum/strCount);
```

Comment: No, just put continue behind strCount = strCount + 1, then you don't need an else, and the return Math.round only happens after the loop is completed!

Comment: @Icepickle Nice catch. I have made some modification

Comment: What do you think the first `if` does? there is no need for an `else if` branch if you use `continue` the `if` branch

Comment: @Icepickle I have taken out the ```continue``` as I would like to clearly state out each of the case.

Comment: @Loolii Glad that helps